# How Can I change according to the size of the device

Tags: java, android, xml

I want change according to the size of the device so I want make responsive app . How Can I? How Can I support multiple device size?

How it looks on Nexus S 4.7":

[image: It looks on Nexus S 4.7"]

How it looks on Pixel:

[image: It looks on Pixel]

Comment: What specifically do you want to fix? generic questions will lead to generic answers

Answer (score 0):

Use `dp` whenever specifying sizes other than TextSizes

Use `sp` while specifying text sizes

Use `RelativeLayout` in your xml so it will adjust according to the screen sizes

Comment: I did use this but ıt cant work . It s looks half

Comment: "Looks Half" ? Could you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

Use SP whenever you want to make text user dependent
That means if user has set large text size in his/her device then all texts in all app's whos dimensions are in sp automatically change in large text. Therefore it is recommended to you sp in text size
Whereas dp is fix and no user settings are apply on dp therefore it is recommended to you dp dimensions with elements you to fix like margins and paddings

For your problem providing 'dp' should work perfectly but if it is not working they you might have some other problem therefore try to provide more details about your project

For more details read this:-
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `ConstraintLayout`
2. Use `match_parent` and `wrap_content` instead of fixed values for views.
3. Use `dp` and `sp` instead of fixed units for the size of the views and the size of the text respectively.
4. Create multiple layouts according to the different sizes of the screens.

You can get more details about it on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

By the way, to create multiple layouts for a particular layout, go to the design tab of the layout. Click on the `Orientation for Preview` [image: the icon] icon in the toolbar. From the drop-down list that has appeared, select **Create Other...**. Now a dialog might have appeared. Do not change anything except on the left side of the dialog, there will be an **Available qualifiers** section. Select **Smallest screen width** or **Smallest width** (according to the options available). Click the **>>** symbol and enter the minimum width of the screen you want to design the layout for. For example, you enter "600dp", then the layout created will be for devices with 600 or more width (dp) as their screen width. Click **Ok** and a new layout will be created for a different set of screen sizes.